# windows server 2008 IIS 7.5 maximum file accept limit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

I have deployed my application on IIS 7.5 on windows server 2008 operating system and i want to know what is the maximum file upload limit and how to increase that limit? Im working on asp.net mvc2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This setting configures the upload file size limit:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="10485760"/>
            </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Default size is ~30Mb.

Answer (score 4):

Set your web.config with the following where xxx is the max upload size in kilobytes:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxx" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The default is 4096 (= 4 MB).  [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Read [this](http://frazsundal.blogspot.com/2011/02/request-filtering-module-is-configured.html)  blog post and you will find out what is the maximum length and how to increase its limit

Comment: Thanks alex but the link you provide is my own blog:)